# Rails create action is redirecting to index when it should be rendering the new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

If I submit a new user form with errors, it redirects to the index page and then renders the new page on top of it. In the controller I specify that it should just render the new action so that the user can see/fix their errors and resubmit. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Here's the create action in my controller code:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.role = "owner"

  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "Registration successful!"
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = "You have errors!"
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'redirects to the index page then renders the new page on top of it.' That's not possible. It either rendered new or redirected to index. Are there any filters on your controller that may be interfering? Also, you'll probably want to redirect to :show for the new user from inside if @user.save. Otherwise Rails will attempt to render a 'create' view, which you probably don't have.

Comment: the address goes from http://localhost:3000/users/new to http://localhost:3000/users, but its actually showing the new user page. And even if I view page source it shows the index source... It's really weird. Yeah I have it redirect to show now, thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figured it out? In my case, redirection i a wrong way, because i need to preserve the data, entered by user and show errors, that he can fix

Comment: I think the reason why you end up at /users instead of /users/new is that the actual request is POST /users. It renders the :new view because of the 'render :new'

Comment: Did you or @AntonAL figure this out? I'm having the same issue. This happens when the user input fails validation and then they resubmit. The resubmission directs them to index instead of new.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to say

```
redirect_to :action => 'new'
```

Comment: Not necessarily. They may want to re-render the form with the values given by the user. render :new ought to be fine here.

Comment: Yeah redirect works but it doesn't show the errors or anything then.